# in linux( raspbian) opencv set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 60) is not working

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I just want to change fps in real time Image processing but fps is not changed

How can i deal with that problem

some people said that you have to intall libv4l-dev and v412-ctl

so i intall using apt-get intall  and next how can i solve this problem?

this is my source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;

    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT, CV_8UC3);
    Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS,60);
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320 );
    Camera.set( CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240);

    if (!Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening the camera"<<endl;return -1;}

    while(1){
        Camera.grab();
        Camera.retrieve ( image);

        cv::cvtColor(image, image, cv::COLOR_BGR2RGB);
        int fps = (int)(Camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS));
        cout << "fps" << fps << endl;
        cv::imshow( "test", image );
        if ( cv::waitKey(1) > 0 ) break;

    }

    Camera.release();
}
```

just cout is 30!!! not 60 
raspberry camera support 640x480p 60/90fps !!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my english isn't perfect, my first language is french.

You can't change the FPS, because in `raspicam_cv.cpp CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` isn't a valuable parameter in function set() it do nothing. Also, it is the same to CV_CAP_PROP_MODE.

And get function with CV_CAP_PROP_FPS parameter always sends 30.

To have more fps, go to the file where you install raspicam and go to `src/private/private_impl.cpp`

At line 66, you will find  `void Private_Impl::setDefaultStateParams()` 
change the value of `State.framerate` to 60. After that, go to line 530 and comment the following line:

```
if ( shutter > 330000 )
    shutter = 330000;
```

Finally, rebuild and make and make install again. That worked to me.

Comment: I don't understand the first line, could you please [edit] your post and explain what you mean? Thank you!

Comment: that is better?

Comment: Better, but still not so clear. Let me try: are we talking about [this raspicam_cv.cpp here](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/src/raspicam_cv.cpp)? I see `bool RaspiCam_Cv::set ( int propId, double value )`, and `propId` can be `CV_CAP_PROP_FPS`. Are you saying that this doesn't work?

Comment: No we don't have the same code. My code doesn't have setFrame and setSensorMode function. So in your case it work, but you will be limited by shutterSpeed. The solution is remove the line about earlier in private_impl.cpp.